# Configuring TSCONFIG.JSON Paths using * (Substitution)

Tags: typescript, path, tsconfig

I have a folder, where it contains many other folders with different names.
All these folders have a /src/lib/ with the files that I need to share.

right now it's like this:

```
"paths": {
"@example/api1/*": ["./projects/APIs/api1/src/lib/*"],
"@example/api2/*": ["./projects/APIs/api2/src/lib/*"],
"@example/api3/*": ["./projects/APIs/api3/src/lib/*"],
}
```

and we need a solution to have all in 1 line
like the one below:

```
"paths": {
"@example/APIs/*": ["./projects/APIs/*/src/lib/*"],
}
```

The use of 2 "*" is not allowed by typescript and I cannot find another way to do this.

any alternative to this?

I already tried, but it didn't work:

```
"@example/APIs/*": ["./projects/APIs/*"]"
```

Comment: What does `it didn't work` mean exactly? To me, `"@example/APIs/*": ["./projects/APIs/*"]"` looks exactly like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cuzy. 
I cant say why it doesn't work. It just can't find the paths when using the quick Fix to Import. It just says it cant find and no quick fixes available.